# Sum of the translated quadratic roots of the unity

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While reading [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003491689903229?via%3Dihub), I stumbled on this formula:$$\Big|\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \exp\left(\left(2\pi i/p\right)\left(ak^2+bk\right)\right)\Big| = \sqrt p$$
For any prime odd $p$ and any $a,b \in \mathbb N$ where $a\neq0$.

I'm having a hard time convincing myself that this formula is true. The simpler case where $b=0$ is a known result of [Gaussian sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum) but the way to generalize it still evades me. How would one prove it?

Comment: What is $n$ in $e^{\frac{2 \pi  i}{n}(a k^2+b k)}$?

Comment: @Raffaele Edit: It's p. I changed the notation of the paper but forgot an n. oups!